# Combobox item preview

Tags: c#

I have a combobox with items(paths of opened files with opendialog).

[Screenshot http://screenshotuploader.com/i/01/0k8n94fka.png](http://screenshotuploader.com/i/01/0k8n94fka.png)

How to show only files name in combobx preview?

```
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Выбрать фаил для загрузки";
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see how any of the other answers here would work so thought i'd help out

Just use [SafeFileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames.aspx) instead of `FileNames`,

`SafeFileNames:` Gets an array of file names and extensions for all the selected files in the dialog box. **The file names do not include the path.**

e.g.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a custom class, which looks like this:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
     public string Display{get;set;}
     public string Value{get;set;}
     public override ToString()
     {
          return this.Display.ToString();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

r u binding the combobox with the entire path..??

Comment: Just try this code to extract filename Path.GetFileName(YourPath); Add the resultant string to combobox

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code to extract filename
**Path.GetFileName(YourPath);**
Add the resultant string to combobox